# android - Energy consumption of collecting smartphone information

Tags: android, performance, energy

I have an application that collects a bunch of smartphone information, e.g. Wi-Fi and cellular conditions or number of processors running. Now I want to profile the energy consumption of collecting all these data.

Is there any statement about reading data from the API? I looked for it, but only found information about sensors, which didn't include the information I'm currently using.

EDIT: Also, what is the energy cost of the application if I set it to only collect data when `RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION` is broadcasted? That is, how much energy is consumed while the application waits for the broadcast information?

Comment: Ive used the tool mentioned here with success https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus5x/comments/3y8144/guide_finding_battery_issues_with_googles_battery/ it is not nexus only

Comment: Do you want to minimize the energy consumption of your data collection? I can make recommendations as to techniques. Or do you just want to profile the consumption of each API (which is going to be dependent upon everything else you're doing)?

Comment: @TaylorKidd The idea is to minimize the energy consumption, having the numeric value of each iteration of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any statement about reading data from the API?

There is nothing in the Android SDK for power profiling. You are welcome to look at Qualcomm's [Trepn](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/trepn-power-profiler) profiler, though [its license agreement has issues](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/02/27/qualcomm-trepn-eula-nonsense.html).